# Why do I get "No opponent found" all time when trying to search in Seasons mode?

Tags: fifa-13

At FIFA 13 I get "No opponent found" all time when trying to search in Seasons mode, even the firewall status is OPEN. Can anyone help ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because I didn't apply the newest update yet. Updating the game solves this

Comment: If you've solved your own issue, go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer.